# Efficiency of frequently called function initializing an array in JS

Tags: javascript, caching, memory, garbage-collection

I have some code that can parse hundreds of objects (coming from network requests). This code will then call a function to see if it matches a value.

I.E.

```
(1..100+){
    isMatch(foo);
}

function isMatch(foo) {
    const matches = ["apple", "orange", "strawberry"];
    return matches.includes(foo);
}
```

My question is how JS handles the 'matches' array being created. The isMatch function could potentially be called 100+ times. Is it constantly instantiating this array in memory every single time, or will it automatically cache it? Or, is this not really a problem with memory because the size of the array and GC?

Also, any performance differences between using array.includes vs. a regex for the actual matching?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have any hard evidence for this but it feels like the `matches` array won't be cached. Then again, it might, I'm not sure. It seems like a compiler can deduce that it needs to keep one copy of this array, instead of many, especially after you call the function several times.

Comment: _"Also, any performance differences between..."_ -> jsperf.com

Comment: `const` is scoped to the function, and so gets created and destroyed over and over and over. If you have a fixed list, declare it in a broader scope and either refer to it directlyin `isMatch`, or pass it as argument like `isMatch(foo, LIST_OF_MATCHES)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` is [scoped to the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), and so gets created and destroyed over and over and over. If you have a fixed list, declare it in a broader scope and either refer to it directly in `isMatch`, or pass it as argument like `isMatch(foo, LIST_OF_MATCHES)`

Comment: Are you sure this will not be JIT optimised? I don't know myself but it *seems* like it could be. If it's an array that's created all the time, and it's always the same, never is mutated, then it seems like it could be optimised to only be created once and not be GC'd.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, I was hoping JS'd take care of that automatically

Comment: It might be, but this was not a question about a specific vendor's JS engine with JIT compilation. As far as just JavaScript is concerned, `const` is scoped, and will constantly get rebuilt. If someone makes a compiler that's more efficient about that, that's cool but not technically part of this question.